# How to assign matrix elements to indices in a list in R?

Tags: r

I want to do something like this:

```
A = matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 8)
for (ind in list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(1,6), c(2,7), c(3,8))){
  # print(ind)
  A[ind] = 1
  }
```

Printing `ind` gives me what I expect (line `1, 2` then `2,3` and so on), but after running this loop `A` is:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

and I have really no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, same premise.

```r
A <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 8)
lst <- list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(1,6), c(2,7), c(3,8))

A[t(list2DF(lst))] <- 1
A
```

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

To answer your question of why the loop will not work, you need to transpose the index.

```r
A = matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 8)
for (ind in list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(1,6), c(2,7), c(3,8))){
  # print(ind)
  A[t(ind)] = 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. But can you explain why R works this way? It is so counterintuitive, for example in Python if you pass a tuple of arguments, e.g. `(1,2)` they are used in the same order `1` then `2`. When indexing a matrix in R we pass `row` and then `column`, right? So why passing `c(row, col)` gives `A[col, row]`???

Comment: This can probably explain it better than I can. The 3rd example down is what you are experiencing. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#matrix-subsetting

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
A[do.call(`rbind`, lst)] <- 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```